# Android MediaPlayer setDataSourceFD fails on a Pantech Crossover

Tags: android, debugging

Our engine creates mediaplayer with:

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
final AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescritor = pContext.getAssets().openFd(MusicFactory.sAssetBasePath + pAssetPath);
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetFileDescritor.getFileDescriptor(), assetFileDescritor.getStartOffset(), assetFileDescritor.getLength());
mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

it works great on all phones except Pantech Crossover (Android 2.2.1) where it crashes the game with:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
  at org.anddev.andengine.audio.music.MusicFactory.createMusicFromAsset
```

Any ideas how to solve this or what's happening here?